# Modify terminal STDOUT/STDERR to change the line colour based on a REGEX

Tags: bash, regex, stdout, stderr

Is this possible?  What I would like to achieve is when running unit tests (Python) to highlight any line which matches the path to the current project directory and leave other output untouched.  Generally these are the line I am searching for so it would be really useful for debugging purposes.  The pattern matching part should be fine, I just don't know how to go about modifying the output (tests are being run with Nose)

Answer (score 1):

You could pipe your command through `grep -C10000 -P --color pattern` (or, in your specific case, `grep -C10000 -P --color ".*$PWD.*"`).

For example:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -C10000 -P --color 'GHz|MHz'
```

- Yes, this is an useless use of cat.
- `-C10000` tells grep to print 10000 lines of context. Use a number big enough to make grep print all lines
- Use `|&` if you want to also capture STDERR

Comment: You may need to match `"^.*$PWD/.*$"` if you want to highlight the whole line containing the current directory.

Comment: Right, answer updated. No need for `^` and `$` however. I've also removed the final slash.

Comment: You also might use `egrep --color "$|^.*$PWD/.*$"` to grep all lines to avoid the use of -C10000. This way `egrep` will find all lines and highlight found matches. But since a EOL ($) is not 'visible' only the actual search pattern is colored.